# What's wrong with my if else statement?

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

I am having a hard time figuring out what's wrong with my code. Here is my code and when i run it it displays the same word all over again even though i entered different numbers. Please help me, thanks a lot.

```
int main()
{
    const int size = 4;
    double arr[size];
    int i;

    cout << "Input numbers: ";

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(0<=arr[i]<=5)
        {
            cout << "HEY" << endl;
        }
        else if(0>arr[i])
        {
            cout << "Hello" << endl;
        }
        else if(10<arr[i]<20)
        {
            cout << "Haha" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Hoho";
        }

    }

    cin.ignore();   cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do `0<=arr[i]<=5` in C++; it'll be interpreted as `(0<=arr[i]) <=5`, and since `(0<=arr[i])` is either `0` or `1` it will always be true. You'll have to use `0<=arr[i] && arr[i]<=5`. Same thing with `10<arr[i]<20`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing a variable to a range of values in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830644/comparing-a-variable-to-a-range-of-values-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

This `if(0<=arr[i]<=5)` should be written as:

```
if( arr[i] >= 0 && arr[i] <= 5 )
```

This `else if(10<arr[i]<20)` as

```
else if( 10 < arr[i] && arr[i] < 20 )
```

When you want logical `anding` of conditions, i.e., you want both conditions to be true you should use the [`&&`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) operator. If the first test fails the other does not need to be evaluated:

From msdn link given above:

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I forgot that one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only the range that's wrong (as others pointed out). With

```
    else if(0>arr[i])
    {
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
    }
    else if(10<arr[i]<20)
    {
        cout << "Haha" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Hoho";
    }
```

only the first `else if` ("Hello") will be executed for positive arr[i]. It catches all numbers greater than 5.