# C: What does if(a<b<c) do?

Tags: c

why does the following if-statement return 1 (true)?

```
int main() {
    short a = 1;
    short b = 5;
    short c = 4;

    if (a<b<c)
        printf("true \n");
    else
        printf("false \n");

    return 0;
}
```

It is obviously not the same as

```
if(a<b && b<c)
```

because this returns false.

Thank you

Comment: `a<b` returns 1, `1<c` is true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing a variable to a range of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830644/comparing-a-variable-to-a-range-of-values) (I know that's for C++ but this seem to be one of those cases where it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 5):

The relational operators (<, <=, >, >=) are read from left to right (and have the same precedence) as you can see here: [Operator precedence](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm). Therefore

```
a < b
```

is evaluated first. The result of this evaluation (true or false then) will take part in the next evaluation

```
(1 or 0) < c
```

Essentially your code is the same as

```
 if ((a<b)<c)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `a<b` statement is equal to true or `1`. so we can say `a<b` or `1` is less than `c`.

```
printf(a<b);    // result is 1
printf(1 < c)   // result is true because 1 is less than 4
```

So this statement `(a<b<c)` is `true`

***[try online](http://cpp.sh/5hlcn)***

Answer (score 2):

The `<` operator has left-to-right associativity.  So your expression is parsed as follows:

```
(a<b)<c
```

So `a<b` is first evaluated.  Since `a` is less that `b` it evaluates to true, i.e. 1.  So now you have:

```
1<c
```

Since `c` is 4 this is also true, so the final result is 1.