# Why does the condition salary between 1500 and 1000 not work?

Tags: c

```
float salary;
printf("Hello !\n");
printf("This program calculates the net salary for an employee in a company. \n");
printf("please input the salary for the employee :  \n");
scanf("%f", &salary);
if (salary>=5000){
    printf("The salary for the employee is %f" ,salary-( salary*15/100));
}
else if (salary>=3000){
    printf("The salary for the employee is %f", salary-salary*10/100);
}
else if (salary<3000){
    printf("The salary for the employee is %f", salary-salary*5/100);
}
else if (1500>salary>1000){
    printf("The salary for the employee is %f", salary+200);
}
else{
    printf("The salary of the employee is less than 1000");
}
```

Comment: `1500>salary>1000` is not valid C. Try `if ((1500>salary) && (salary >1000))` instead. EDIT: see below as well, @Bib noticed another problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing a variable to a range of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830644/comparing-a-variable-to-a-range-of-values)

Comment: @MortenJensen Actually, `1500>salary>1000` is valid C, but it doesn't do what the OP thinks it does.

Answer (score 1):

You have already tested for it:

```
else if (salary<3000){
    printf("The salary for the employee is %f", salary-salary*5/100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if `1500>salary>1000` were reached its evaluation does not suit its intended purpose.

To illustrate, set `salary = 1400`.  Note that `1400` is less than `1500`, and it is greater than `1000`, but the segment will be skipped.  Here is why:

Evaluating from left to right, the expression `1500>salary` resolves to `1` (`true`).   then `1>1000` evaluates to `0`, (`false`) thus skipping that segment.

But in your code because the expression:

```
   else if (salary<3000){
```

evaluates to `true`, the `if else` construct is satisfied, and no other segments are evaluated.  The code also leaves gaps between some ranges.  (eg. 1500 & 3000).

The following example illustrates evaluations of this kind using a `value >= x = && value < y` syntax.

```
if(salary < 1000){
    ...
}
else if (salary >= 1000 && salary < 1500){
    ...
}
else if (salary >= 1500 && salary < 3000){
    ...
}
else if (salary >= 3000 && salary < 5000){
    ...
}
else {
    //salary >= 5000
}
```

Comment: The compound conditions aren't necessary if you do the comparisons in strict descending order: `if (a > 5000) {...} else if (a > 3000) {...} else if (a > 1500) {...} else {...}`

Comment: @Ray - No, they are not.  The same is true even for strict _ascending_ order if using the `<` operator.  But as is allows for _any_ order.  (It is just a preference, but either way works.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
float salary;
printf("Hello !\n");
printf("This program calculates the net salary for an employee in a company. \n");
printf("please input the salary for the employee :  \n");
scanf("%f", &salary);
if (salary>=5000){
    printf("The salary for the employee is %f" ,salary-( salary*15/100));
}
else if (salary>=3000){
    printf("The salary for the employee is %f", salary-salary*10/100);
}
else if (salary<3000 && salary >= 1500){
    printf("The salary for the employee is %f", salary-salary*5/100);
}
else if (salary >= 1000 && salary < 1500){
    printf("The salary for the employee is %f", salary+200);
}
else{
    printf("The salary of the employee is less than 1000");
}
```